# Cleaner way to initialize & populate a new List<>?

Tags: c#, linq, syntax

Without using a method after creating the List, and without using an array or new List<>(array), is there syntax to make this code cleaner?

```
List<CustomObject> list = new List<CustomObject> 
{ 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject(), 
    new CustomObject()  
};
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this, when initializing? Something like...

```
List<CustomObject> list = new List<CustomObject> { new CustomObject() * 10 };
```

Comment: A simple For loop?

Comment: Of course I could use an Array. I don't want to use an array. I want to use a List<>, and to populate it when I create the List.

Comment: You could do it with a for loop

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => new CustomObject()).ToList()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to make use of [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                     .Select(i => new CustomObject())
                     .ToList();
```

**Update**

Definitely using the above code is slower that using the collection initializer you have already used, as correctly [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) has pointed out in his comment. In order to measure how slower is this approach than the collection initializer approach I set up the following test case and I used the [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) library

```
public class CustomObject
{
}

public class ListInitiator
{
    [Benchmark]
    public List<CustomObject> InitializeList()
    {
        return new List<CustomObject>
        {
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject(),
            new CustomObject()
        };
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<CustomObject> InitializeListUsingEnumerableRange()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(i => new CustomObject())
            .ToList();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<ListInitiator>();
    }
}
```

Below you can find the results of the Test

```
Processor=Intel Core i5 CPU 760 2.80GHz (Nehalem), ProcessorCount=4
Frequency=2732435 Hz, Resolution=365.9739 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2110.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2110.0

 |                             Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
 |----------------------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
 |                     InitializeList | 319.6 ns | 3.904 ns | 3.260 ns |
 | InitializeListUsingEnumerableRange | 642.4 ns | 9.139 ns | 8.549 ns |
```

It's more than clear that if you make use of `Enumerable.Range` approach you need *more than the double time* of using the collection initializer approach. However in both cases you are significantly under 1ms. Based on the latter fact you can't tell that this is a performance hit or not. There are systems that this difference would be a great performance hit. On the other hand there are systems that this difference wouldn't have been noticeable in any way.

Comment: That will create only one `CustomObject` and repeat it 10 times, not 10 new `CustomObject`s.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with a good old for loop?

```
var myList = new List<CustomObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myList.Add(new CustomObject());
}
```

Comment: Does C# allow you to use a loop outside of a method?

Comment: C# allows only declarations outside of methods. There is no reason for you not to initialize the list in a constructor or other method. Populating it entirely when you declare it isn't good practice.

Comment: Do it in a constructor.

Comment: You haven't mentioned *why* you can't or don't want to do this in a method. If you did, you might get better suggestions.

Comment: That one was not really concise, so i've replaced it with a summary.

Comment: "You haven't mentioned why you can't or don't want to do this in a method. " I don't have to mention why I can't/don't want to. I edited the question to include the restrictions. I am just trying to learn & grow my knowledge with C#. I already know I could use an array or use List<CustomObject>(array). Thank you though.

Comment: Of course, you don't have to mention anything. We only request information about the context to avoid the oh-so-common [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that many askers fall into. Besides, even if you're sure yours isn't one of those cases, the more context you give the more relevant information we can give you.

Comment: If you do it this way, you may wish to pass `10` (or whatever `Capacity` to the `List` constructor) to get it initialised to the right size.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too simple but can't you create your own specialized list?
Something like:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : new()
{
    public MyList(T o, int times)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            this.Add(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just curious if there was a way to do it during initialization of the List. Well, I know that having it done in a constructor does exactly that, but I was just looking if there was syntax to do it as I showed in the second code snippet. Thanks.